# meaning of underlying

Tags: meaning

> The pool of loans **underlying** the mortgage bond conformed to the standards, in their size and the credit quality of the borrowers, set by one of several government agencies: Freddie Mac, Fannie Mae, and Ginnie Mae.-*The Big Short: Inside the Doomsday Machine* by Michael Lewis

I've searched meaning of the word "underlying" and found several meanings, but I'm not sure of which one is correct one.

a)Lying or situated under something. [Lexico.com]

b)used to describe something on which something else is based [Cambridge dictionary]

c)anterior and prior in claim [Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Personally, I'd expect ***underpinning*** here, but what do I know? Presumably, the "mortgage bond" is a big pot of money to be lent out to potential home-buyers. And that big pot of money *itself* came from ***loans from lenders*** (banks, private investors, etc.). So those loans from cash-rich lenders ***underlie / underpin / support / give rise to / create / maintain*** the pot of money to be lent on to cash-poor mortgagees.

Comment: I'd agree **underpinning** seems more common, but it has more of a sense of something acting as a guarantee, which is in conflict with the subject of *The Big Short* (unsecured or inadequately secured loans causing financial disaster), so maybe the filmmakers wanted to emphasise a looser connection between bond and mortgage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Underlying* is often used when speaking of financial derivatives. The derivative financial instrument (say a bond pool of mortgages or a call option on a stock) derives some of its value from the *underlying* instrument (the mortgages or the stock).

The closest meaning is the OP's second definition.

> used to describe something on which something else is based

Here's a description of a bond pool, also called a Mortgage-Backed Security (MBS):

> GNMAs are mortgage-backed securities that are issued by the Government National Mortgage Association (a.k.a. Ginnie Mae) and guaranteed by the federal government. For those not familiar with mortgage-backed securities, Vanguard describes them this way:
>
> > MBS are an investment in a pool of mortgage loans, which are the underlying asset and provide cash flow for the securities. MBS are commonly referred to as “pass-through” securities, as the principal and interest of the underlying mortgage loans “passes through” to the investor. All bondholders receive a monthly pro-rata distribution of principal and interest over the life of the security.

Source: [How Do GNMA Bonds Work?](https://obliviousinvestor.com/how-do-gnma-bonds-work/)

An important point that Michael Lewis was making in *The Big Short* is that the bond pools *should have* derived their credit quality from the underlying mortgages. The rating agencies, Moody's and S&P, *should have* lowered the ratings of the bond pools to reflect the lower ratings of the underlying mortgages.

The falling of the Jenga block tower in the movie was a vivid way to describe the consequences of failing to have the derived instruments correctly reflect the value and quality of the underlying instruments.

Comment: Thanks, It helped a lot.